# Mocking logging of a module imported with a relative import

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

Due to the structure of our project and the way we run its tests, our library modules are imported with a relative import by test modules, for example:

```
from .. import foo_bar
```

Now, I want to check that a function in the `foo_bar` module issues a warning for certain parameters. I have tried this:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch('foo_bar.logging')
def test_distance(mock_logging):
    foo_bar.baz(None)
    assert mock_logging.warn.called
```

and I got this:

```
target = 'foo_bar'

    def _importer(target):
        components = target.split('.')
        import_path = components.pop(0)
>       thing = __import__(import_path)
E       ImportError: No module named 'foo_bar'

/tmp/envs/foo/lib/unittest/mock.py:1058: ImportError
```

When I tried to change the patch line like this:

```
@patch('..foo_bar.logging')
```

I got this error:

```
target = '..foo_bar'

    def _importer(target):
        components = target.split('.')
        import_path = components.pop(0)
>       thing = __import__(import_path)
E       ValueError: Empty module name

/tmp/envs/foo/lib/unittest/mock.py:1058: ValueError
```

Any idea how to use the `patch` function from `unittest.mock` in these circumstances?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the imported module's `__name__` attribute to achieve relative import mocking.

```
@patch(foo_bar.__name__ + '.logging')
def test_distance(mock_logging):
    ...
```